# Wysiwyg editor field is redirecting to 404 error in the front end form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, 404-page, wysiwyg

We are facing strange issues, we have a form with wysiwyg-editor as a field, while saving, the form is redirecting to `404 error: Page not found.`, if we remove below script then everything is working/saving fine. But we want implement/add wysiwyg-editor field in our template.

Can any one help us on this.

**Html :**

```
   <textarea type="text" id="company_description"
            name="company_description" title="company_description"
            class="input-text companydesc wysiwyg-editor" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo strip_tags($sellerDetails->getDesc());?>
   </textarea>
```

**Script :**

```
<script>
                        require([
                            'jquery',
                            'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
                        ], function(jQuery){

                            var config = '',
                                editor;

                            jQuery.extend(config, {
                                settings: {
                                    theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,',
                                    theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
                                    theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
                                    theme_advanced_buttons4: null,
                                    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: null
                                },
                                files_browser_window_url: false
                            });
                    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
                                'company_description',
                                config
                            );
                           editor.turnOn();
                           jQuery('#company_description')
                            .addClass('wysiwyg-editor')
                            .data(
                                'wysiwygEditor',
                                editor
                            );
                         });
                        </script>
```